# Google Sheets API (Java) - Update Formatting

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am having trouble finding the documentation on updating format with the API in Java. My goal is to modify row heights and cell background colors. Does anyone know how this is accomplished or could link me to the documentation, please?

I am using Google Sheet API v4.

**EDIT:**

As I review, I realize now that the Google API docs are actually easy to read. Thanks to all who helped me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Adjusting column width or row height**](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#adjust_column_width_or_row_height)

- You can use [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) to modify row height using [updateDimensionProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatedimensionpropertiesrequest) request

[**Setting cell background color**](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)

- You can use [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) to modify background color using [updateCells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest) request
- Background color can be configured in [rows](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#rowdata) -> [values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#celldata) -> [userEnteredFormat](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#cellformat) -> [backgroundColor](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#color)
- [Color](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#color) values to be used for red, blue and green ranges from 0 - 1.
- [range](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#gridrange) determines the range of cells where the new cell properties will be applied

Example on how to set color to blue:

```
blue = 255/255 = 1
red = 0/255 = 0
green = 0/255 = 0
```

**Sample Request Body:**

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateCells": {
        "rows": [
          {
            "values": [
              {
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                  "backgroundColor": {
                    "blue": 1,
                    "red": 0,
                    "green": 0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "range": {
          "endColumnIndex": 1,
          "endRowIndex": 1,
          "sheetId": 0,
          "startColumnIndex": 0,
          "startRowIndex": 0
        },
        "fields": "userEnteredFormat"
      }
    },
    {
      "updateDimensionProperties": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": 0,
          "dimension": "ROWS",
          "startIndex": 0,
          "endIndex": 2
        },
        "properties": {
          "pixelSize": 160
        },
        "fields": "pixelSize"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]

**Additional References:**

[Java Quickstart - How to use Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java)

[Basic Formatting - How to change appearance of sheets and cells](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/formatting)

[Sheets API -Samples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples)

[Sheets API - REST Resources](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest)